# How can I redirect multiple paths in a domain to different AWS load balancers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I want to host all my REST services on one single domain in AWS. (Each REST service is hosted in AWS beanstalk, using EC2 and load balancers so that each service can autoscale depending on usage)

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
https://api.foo.com/product-service -> product REST service
https://api.foo.com/attribute-service -> attribute REST service
https://api.foo.com/login-service -> login REST service
...
```

But I'm pretty new to AWS, so I'm not sure how can I achieve this, do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear  what you can do?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks! your comment helped me out! I ended up going with cloudfront, using multiple origins to each backend service

Comment: So this is what I ended up doing: I created an origin for each backend service with empty path. 

Then I had to create a behavior for each backend service, each by adding the path that I want them to point (i.e. /storage-service or /product-service)

After that I had to add a context path or add the same prefix to each service. So to call storage service I actually had to add that to my url mappings.
And now it´s working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this from Route53 as R53 is not aware of any url paths. If you want to use R53 for that your domains must be:

```
product-service.api.foo.com
attribute-service.api.foo.com 
login-service.api.foo.com
```

This would be the easiest way to achieve that, as you would just create **alias records** to different EBs. Otherwise I think you have to do add [CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) to your setup and associates different origins with different API servers of yours based on the path.